# Notepad++ Setting for Disabling Auto-open Previous Files

Tags: notepad++

[image]

How do I stop Notepad++ from loading all files from the past session?

Every time I open a file I have 10 other open tabs with all my past files. I don't want that. When I hit the close button I expect the program to do what I want and close it. If I wanted to save a session I would use the built in session save feature. I don't want to hit the gray x 20 times when I am done so next time I don't have a bunch of files opening and taking up memory.

I tried the -nosession parameter and that works. But it only works if I use the shortcut. It won't work if I use the right-click edit method. How do I set Notepad++ to do this?

Answer (score 593, accepted):

For versions 6.6+ you need to uncheck "Remember the current session for next launch" on `Settings -> Preferences -> Backup`.

[image: this is it in 6.6+]

For older versions you need to uncheck "Remember the current session for next launch" 
on `Settings -> Preferences`.

[image: this is it]

Comment: @jhurtado -- After opening a *very* large file in Notepad++ and restarting, the application freezes... can I "disable" auto-opening by deleting the Notepad++ cache?

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. BTW, "BACKUP "is a weird name for an option about auto load recent file......Just wondered why the developer named it.

Comment: this should be a default setting. No one wants the old stuff to keep coming up

Comment: Backup options seems a weird place to put that particular option.

Answer (score 59):

In Notepad++ v6.6 this setting is moved to the Backup tab of the Preferences menu.

[image]

Comment: I added your response to the original answer :)

Comment: Oh, the BACKUP tab, of course that's where I should find settings related to launch.  How stupid of me.

Comment: I agree with your sarcastic remark, pseudocoder.  I looked around in the program quite a bit before coming here for the answer.  I never would have thought backup had anything to do with this (as it's not backup related, though there is a session backup option).

Answer (score 53):

My problem was that Notepad++ was crashing on a file I had previously opened; I was unable to open the application at all. [This blog post](https://tompai.pro/computers/solutions-remove-last-file-from-notepad-startup/) discusses how to delete the data from the "Sessions" file so that Notepad++ will open without having any prior files open:

From the blog post:

> Method 1 - edit session.xml
>
> 1. Open file session.xml in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++ or %APPDATA%\Notepad++
> 2. Delete its contents and save it
> 3. Run Notepad++ , session.xml will get new content automatically
>
> Method 2 - add the -nosession parameter to Notepad++ shortcut
>
> 1. Create a desktop shortcut referring to your Notepad++ program, e.g. C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
> 2. Right click on this shortcut
> 3. In the "Target" field add the -nosession parameter so the target field looks exaxtly like (apostrophes included too): "C:\Program
>      Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -nosession
> 4. Save and run Notepad++ from this shortcut icon with no recent files

**Note:** This is not a permanent setting, this simply deletes the prior session's information / opened files and starts over.

Alternatively, if you know the file which is causing notepad++ to hang, you can simply rename the file and open notepad++. This will solve the problem.

I hadn't seen this solution listed when I was googling my problem so I wanted to add it here!

Comment: This was perfect for my similar situation; I closed Notepad++ while I had a huge file open from a network share, and it rendered Notepad++ unresponsive for a long time when I tried to start it again. I killed the task and then removed the problematic `<File>` element from _session.xml_ before trying again, and that fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @TroyGizzi Glad it helped :)

Comment: This was the answer I was after. No point trying to open Notepad++ if it doesn't even start!

Comment: @Fandango68 Happy it helped you out!

Answer (score 17):

Ok, I had a problem with Notepad++ not remembering that I had chosen not the "Remember Current Session". I tried hacking the config file, but that didn't work. Then I found out that there is a secret config file in your C:\Users\myuseraccount\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++ directory (Windows 7 x64). Mine was empty, meaning who know where the config was really coming from, but I copied over the file with the one in C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++ and now everything works just like you would expect it to.

Comment: The setting is; <GUIConfig name="RememberLastSession">yes</GUIConfig>

Comment: I got angry when the checkbox did not do what it said so I uninstalled. The uninstaller left some files that I had to remove manually.

Answer (score 11):

Go to: `Settings` > `Preferences` > `Backup` > and Uncheck `Remember current session for next launch`

In older versions (6.5-), this option is located on `Settings` > `Preferences` > `MISC`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the menu item *Settings>Preferences*.

On the MISC tab of the resulting dialog, uncheck *"Remember current session for next launch."*

Answer (score 0):

I read the answers.  Then I noticed for me that the check box **was already unchecked**, but it still always reloaded the files.   This is the Settings->Preferences->MISC->"Remember current session for next launch" check box on version 6.3.2.   The following got rid of the problem:

```
1. Check the check box.
2. Exit the program.
3. Start the program again.
4. Uncheck the checkbox.
```