# How to make notepad++ start with a blank new file when opened?

Tags: notepad++

If I double-click on the Notepad++ icon, it opens the last document used. Is there any way to have it default to a blank new document when opened? Is there an argument I can pass in via the shortcut or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [notepad++ setting so it doesnt open old files from previous session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675202/notepad-setting-so-it-doesnt-open-old-files-from-previous-session)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Uncheck the `Remember current session for next launch" checkbox in`Settings->Preferences->MISC`. (Image from Notepad++ v6.4.5 (Aug. 9, 2013), Unicode.)

[image: Notepad++ Settings Dialog image]

As has been noted below. the checkbox has been moved to the Backup tab in more recent versions:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Run it with the launch parameter -nosession

This might be useful f.e if you have opened many documents in previous session and they got lost due to network issue or something else, so Notepad++ produces too much alerts and hangs so you cannot change the parameter in Settings.

Comment: That's it. I need it very often for quick text manipulation or test expression and don't want to change my original settings for global one.

Answer (score 7):

Setting is now on the backup page (Settings > Preferences > Backup page).

Answer (score 4):

Uncheck "Remember the current session for next launch" in Settings -> Preferences.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4675270/2441252