# Notepad++ : Disable old tabs BUT remember last line

Tags: notepad++

Based on the question here: [Notepad++ Setting for Disabling Auto-open Previous Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675202/notepad-setting-for-disabling-auto-open-previous-files)

I want to remember current session during next launch, so that it highlights the last LINE I've worked on for one particular file.

However, I do NOT want to see all my other text files open as tabs when I open notepad++ the next time.

How do I separate these 2 functions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Save this *"particular file"* if it need.
2. Do RMB on it's tab and choose `'Close ALL BUT This'`.
3. Close `Notepad++`.

More convenient will be to create macro.
But your goal's final step is to exit `Npp`... It's unpossible to save macro on closed `Npp` :)

So, do the following

1. Locate where your `Npp` `shortcuts.xml` is placed.
   Possible pathes are:

   - `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`
   - `Npp_install_folder\shortcuts.xml`
   - On path specified in `Npp_install_folder\cloud\choice` (file w/o extension)
2. Go to this place and create new folder in it with name you want, say - `BUP`.
3. Copy original `shortcuts.xml` to `BUP` folder.
4. Create backup copy of `BUP\shortcuts.xml`. Say - `shortcuts_bup.xml`.
5. Open in `Npp BUP\shortcuts.xml` and insert in it's section `<Macros>` the following block:

   ```
       <Macro name="_SaveMe_CloseAllButMe_And_Exit" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
           <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41006" lParam="0" sParam="" />
           <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41005" lParam="0" sParam="" />
           <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41011" lParam="0" sParam="" />
       </Macro>
   ```

Finally, `BUP\shortcuts.xml` should look as:

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <InternalCommands />
    <Macros>
        ' here is something by default ..
        <Macro name="_SaveMe_CloseAllButMe_And_Exit" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
            <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41006" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41005" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41011" lParam="0" sParam="" />
        </Macro>
    </Macros>
    <UserDefinedCommands>
        ' .. and here too. All the rest, reagrdles present it or not, does not concern you.
    </UserDefinedCommands>
    <PluginCommands />
    <ScintillaKeys />
</NotepadPlus>
```

6. Save it.
7. Close all instances of `Npp`.
8. Copy `BUP\shortcuts.xml` over existing `shortcuts.xml` on path you already found.
9. Start `Npp` and reproduce setup you wrote above.
10. Select the line you want on *"particular file"*
11. Choose on meny bar `'Macro -> _SaveMe_CloseAllButMe_And_Exit'`
12. Run `Npp` again.
13. Enjoy (if 13 does not bother you and you are not superstitious :)
    .

Comment: I have done everything correctly up to step 11, but it doesn't bring me back to the same line when I re-open the doc another time.

Also, is there any way I can make it the default, instead of having to navigate the menu bar to run the macro? Thanks!

Comment: @curiousnotepad I tested many times before post it :) My Npp is 7.3.2. Download this [bin-package version](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/7.x/7.3.2/npp.7.3.2.bin.zip) , unzip to any new folder, apply all settings from post. Do not touch anything more. IWFM...